Outlook Search Command for Searching in Folder and Subfolders
Is there a command you can type in the search bar at top in the Outlook Window App to search email within a folder and its subfolders?  I use "folder:FOLDERX" or "folderpath:FOLDERX" for searching emails in hypothetical folder FOLDERX but would like to know if there is a command allowing to search emails in FOLDRX subfolders.

Microsoft Support prodvides search reference tables for Outlook which do not contain optitions to search in folders.

Agree with Markus Meyer, Outlook’s search box is a powerful tool to help you find messages, contacts, tasks, and calendar entries.

I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread,  is this issue resolved now? If so, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

So far no much traction.  Looks like Outlook either can't do what I am trying to do or Microsoft did not documented how.  Thanks.
